# Filtering nested JSON array in javascript and returning inner array which matches a criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I have a json object like this:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "ID": "001",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "value": "BESTSELLERS",
          "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          "value": "Color",
          "identifier": "Green"
        },
        {
          "value": "Size",
          "identifier": "L"
        }
      ],
      "SKUs": [
        {
          "ID": "001_1",
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "value": "BESTSELLERS",
              "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              "value": "Color",
              "identifier": "Green"
            },
            {
              "value": "Size",
              "identifier": "L"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "001_2",
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "value": "BESTSELLERS",
              "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              "value": "Color",
              "identifier": "Yellow"
            },
            {
              "value": "Size",
              "identifier": "M"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "002",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "value": "BESTSELLERS",
          "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          "value": "Size",
          "identifier": "L"
        }
      ],
      "SKUs": [
        {
          "ID": "002_1",
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "value": "BESTSELLERS",
              "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              "value": "Color",
              "identifier": "Black"
            },
            {
              "value": "Size",
              "identifier": "L"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "002_2",
          "Attributes": [
            {
              "value": "BESTSELLERS",
              "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              "value": "Color",
              "identifier": "Grey"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "003",
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "value": "BESTSELLERS",
          "identifier": "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          "value": "Color",
          "identifier": "Blue"
        }
      ],
      "SKUs": []
    }
  ]
}')
```

As you can see, `products` is an array which contains another array `SKUs` which contains another array `Attributes`.

I want to get all those SKUs which have **BOTH** the attributes - `Size` and `Color` for them.

So, it should return

> `SKUs 001_1, 001_2 and 002_1`

So, i wrote the following code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('<MyAboveJSONObjectHere>');
obj.products.filter( p => p.SKUs.filter(sku => sku.Attributes.filter(att => 
att.identifier === 'Color' && att.identifier === 'Size')))
```

> But this is returning all `3` product objects inside the `JSON`.

Can you please tell what is wrong with my code expression ?

Comment: `att.identifier === 'Color' && att.identifier === 'Size'` one property can't hold two different values at a time

Comment: Try `att.identifier === 'Color' || att.identifier === 'Size'`

Comment: since your structure seems standard you can access `1` and `2` index to check whether `color and size` is available or not

Comment: Isnt it att.value=='Color' && att.value=='Size' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `reduce`":

```
data.products.reduce((p, c) => (
  (c.SKUs = c.SKUs.filter(
    sku =>
      sku.Attributes.some(att => att.value === "Color") &&
      sku.Attributes.some(att => att.value === "Size")
  )).length && p.push(c), p ),[]
);
```

```js
data = {
  products: [
    {
      ID: "001",
      Attributes: [
        {
          value: "BESTSELLERS",
          identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          value: "Color",
          identifier: "Green"
        },
        {
          value: "Size",
          identifier: "L"
        }
      ],
      SKUs: [
        {
          ID: "001_1",
          Attributes: [
            {
              value: "BESTSELLERS",
              identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              value: "Color",
              identifier: "Green"
            },
            {
              value: "Size",
              identifier: "L"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          ID: "001_2",
          Attributes: [
            {
              value: "BESTSELLERS",
              identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              value: "Color",
              identifier: "Yellow"
            },
            {
              value: "Size",
              identifier: "M"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "002",
      Attributes: [
        {
          value: "BESTSELLERS",
          identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          value: "Size",
          identifier: "L"
        }
      ],
      SKUs: [
        {
          ID: "002_1",
          Attributes: [
            {
              value: "BESTSELLERS",
              identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              value: "Color",
              identifier: "Black"
            },
            {
              value: "Size",
              identifier: "L"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          ID: "002_2",
          Attributes: [
            {
              value: "BESTSELLERS",
              identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
            },
            {
              value: "Color",
              identifier: "Grey"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ID: "003",
      Attributes: [
        {
          value: "BESTSELLERS",
          identifier: "BEST_SELLER"
        },
        {
          value: "Color",
          identifier: "Blue"
        }
      ],
      SKUs: []
    }
  ]
};

console.log(data.products.reduce((p, c) => (
    (c.SKUs = c.SKUs.filter(
      sku =>
        sku.Attributes.some(att => att.value === "Color") &&
        sku.Attributes.some(att => att.value === "Size")
    )).length && p.push(c), p ),[]
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're wanting to obtain a list of SKU `ID` values from the supplied `products` array where those SKU items has `Attribute` sub-arrays which contained values of `"Color"` and `"Size"`.

This can be achieved via a `reduce()`, where the reduction callback filters SKU items based on the Attributes criteria. Any filtered SKU items are then mapped to their `ID` field, and collected (via `concat()`) into the resulting `output` array as shown below:

```js
const obj={"products":[{"ID":"001","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Green"},{"value":"Size","identifier":"L"}],"SKUs":[{"ID":"001_1","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Green"},{"value":"Size","identifier":"L"}]},{"ID":"001_2","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Yellow"},{"value":"Size","identifier":"M"}]}]},{"ID":"002","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Size","identifier":"L"}],"SKUs":[{"ID":"002_1","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Black"},{"value":"Size","identifier":"L"}]},{"ID":"002_2","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Grey"}]}]},{"ID":"003","Attributes":[{"value":"BESTSELLERS","identifier":"BEST_SELLER"},{"value":"Color","identifier":"Blue"}],"SKUs":[]}]};

/* Filter each product by the required SKU/attribute criteria */
const result = obj.products.reduce((output, product) => {

  /* Determine if this products SKUs have contain requied attribute values */
  return output.concat(product.SKUs.filter((sku) => {

    const attributes = sku.Attributes;

    /* Search the attributes of this sku, looking for any with values that
    are color or size */
    const hasColor = attributes.some((attribute) => attribute.value === 'Color');
    const hasSize = attributes.some((attribute) => attribute.value === 'Size');

    /* If both attribute values found then this sku matches required criteria */
    return hasColor && hasSize;
  })
  /* Map any filtered sku to it's ID and concat the result to output */
  .map(sku => sku.ID));

}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.products.map( p => {
       return p.SKUs.map(sku => {
    return sku.Attributes.filter(att => att.identifier === 'Color' && att.identifier === 'Size')}}
```

Try this, basically you need to first `map` through the arrays and only on the last one `filter`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to check value instead of identifier. Based on your object the value you are checking for is in the value key of the attribute object. You should also be checking for the array length of the return value of the inner filters. An empty array if passed in a condition will still be considered true that's why your filter always returns all the contents of your object. so the filter should look something like this.

```
obj.products.filter( p => p.SKUs.filter( att => att.Attributes.filter(inner => inner.value == 'Color' || inner.value == 'Size').length > 0 ? true : false).length > 0 ? true : false)
```